# how to differentiate fungible and non fungible token transaction in erc1155

Tags: nft

How to identify the transaction of fungible and nonfungible in erc1155. because the mint function is same. if we mint token by amount of one we call this NFT after that if we mint the same token then it increment by one. then how we can call this NFT. please clear my doubt if anyone knows.

Answer (score 0):

The distinction between fungible and non-fungible tokens in ERC-1155 is based on the uniqueness of the token IDs.  When you mint a token with a new, unique token ID, it becomes an NFT. When you mint additional units with the same token ID, they represent fungible tokens.